# Logging out of JS SDK doesn't log out of PHP SDK

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, logout

I have a website that is using both the PHP SDK and JS SDK.

After updating to OAuth in both, I've noticed that logging out of JS doesn't actually log the user out of PHP.

It seems like the general solution is to make a call for '/me' and then, if that errors, assume the user has logged out.  However, I don't need to call /me on every page render, I just want to know whether the user is signed in without the performance hit of a FB API call on every render.

Is there a way for the PHP SDK to be informed of a logout that happened via the JS SDK?

Some things I've tried:

- Comment out the contents of setPersistentData in Facebook.php
- Manually delete the fbsr_::appid:: cookie

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something like ajax call to a page with this [`$facebook->destorySession()`](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L1088) method on the JS callback?

Comment: take a look at this recent update to php SDK: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/commit/4b0e00096c01a959c3f7d9b0655856c17c46383f  maybe you can find it relevant

Comment: The version of the SDK I had didn't have destroySession, this seems to have worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/'); 
unset($_SESSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

get the user access token from facebook library

```
$access_token = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
```

and then use this code in the logout function

```
if ($this->facebook_user)
        { 


        $logoutUrl = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl()."&access_token=".$access_token; 


        redirect($logoutUrl);   
        }
```

And make some changes in facebook library file.

```
 public function getLogoutUrl($params=array()) {
    return $this->getUrl(
      'www',
      'logout.php',
      array_merge(array(
        'next' => $this->getCurrentUrl(),

      ), $params)
    );
  }
```